# Pandas Combining two columns based on whichever column has data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine two columns into a third based on the values.
Original data

```
|Time|  GearUp | GearDn|
|----|---------|-------|  
| 1  |   NaN   |  NaN  |
|2   |  NaN    | DOWN  |
|3   |  NaN    | NaN   |
|4   |  NaN    | NaN   |
|5   |  UP     | NaN   |
|6   |  NaN    | NaN   |
|7   |  NaN    | NaN   |
```

Required result:

```
Time  Gear
1     NaN     
2     DOWN
3     DOWN
4     DOWN
5     UP     
6     UP     
7     UP
```

I tried using the where method but on each column in turn but the second use wrote over the data from the first time.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls explain the logic

Answer (score 0):

use

```
df['Gear'] = df['GearUp'].combine_first(df['GearDown'])
```

refer this link for documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html

Answer (score 0):

use ffill to fill the NaN values (addition to Deepan Solution)

```
df['Gear']=df['GearUp'].combine_first(df['GearDn']).ffill()
df
```

```
    Time    GearUp  GearDn  Gear
0      1       NaN     NaN  NaN
1      2       NaN     DOWN DOWN
2      3       NaN     NaN  DOWN
3      4       NaN     NaN  DOWN
4      5       UP      NaN  UP
5      6       NaN     NaN  UP
6      7       NaN     NaN  UP
```

Comment: @user1412867, did the solution worked for you?